# Deleting Arraylist Items by Index?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm new at coding and i'm trying to practice working with arraylists. Basically in this a user just enters a letter and the program just displays a numbered list of those letters. I'm struggling to figure out how to remove a letter by it's index. Here's a sample of the code:

```
String letter = letterInput.getText();

for (int i = 0; i < lettersList.size(); i++)
    {
        String letterListIndex = lettersList.get(i);
        if (letterListIndex.contains(letter));
        {
            lettersList.remove(letter);
        } 
    }
```

This code seems to just delete every second letter, without delete the inputted number. The tests I've been doing are inputting:

"1. H
2. B
3. K
4. L 
5. J"

And if i try to delete L by typing in 4, it deletes 1. H, 3. K, and 5. J. I'm hoping that make sense.

Overall, I'd like to know how to delete a list item by it's index number. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Pay attention that String is not an ArrayList

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected input/output is? You say the user enters a letter, but then say you entered `4`. That's not a letter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The 4 was the index of the letter i was trying to remove. So on the example list, the 4th number was L. So I was trying to remove L

Comment: So why are you reading in a `String letter`? Should the user enter `L` or `4` to delete `L`?

Comment: The user should have the option to delete by L or by 4. I've got searching by the letter working, but not by the index.

Comment: @quinny see my answer. All you need to do is call `remove(index)` on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) a `String`. It takes an `int` if you want to remove by index.

Scrap your first entire `for` loop and simply do:

```
int letterIndex = Integer.parseInt(letterInput.getText());
lettersList.remove(letterIndex);
```

This is all the code you need

---

If I have a `lettersList`: `{"H", "B", "K", "L", "J"}`

All I need to do is call `lettersList.remove(4-1)` (-1 for 1 indexing) and `lettersList` will now be: `{"H", "B", "K", "J"}`

Comment: The OP isn't calling `remove` on a `String`, but a `List`.

Comment: @Shashwat the parameter is a String. I admit "calling on" is not super precise language.

Comment: Thank you! How would I be able to search for the int in the letters list now? When I put in (letterListIndex.contains(letter), it gave me an error saying the int can't be converted to char qsequence

Comment: @quinny why are you searching for the `int`? I thought your list was all letters.

Comment: The int was searching for the index

Comment: @quinny you *don't need to search for it*. See my updated answer. `remove` removes whatever item is at the given index. It looks like your list is 1-indexed whereas in Java lists are 0-indexed, but you can get around this by just doing `remove(index-1)`

Comment: ahhh okay i got it working! Thank you for your help and patience, I really appreciate it

Comment: @quinny No problem at all.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 4;
    String str = "abcdef";
    String result;
    if (str.length()>index);
    {
        result = str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index+1);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

the index var is the input, and it is 0 based. So if you want to be 1 based, you can set index = index+1

Comment: The OP wants to operate on an `ArrayList`, not a `String`